# Задача на массивы объектов

Tags: java, массивы, функции, циклы, объекты

*Напишите функцию. Функция должна принимать массив городов (название и координаты). И должна возвращать объект содержащий два города, которые находятся друг от друга на наименьшем расстоянии.
Для простоты представим, что все объекты находятся в двумерной плоскости.*

***Классы:***

***Имя класса:*** City, поля: String name, double x, double y.

***Имя класса:*** Result, поля: City first, City second. Город first, должен идти в переданном массиве раньше, чем город second.

***Сигнатура функции:***
Название функции: findClosestCities.

***Параметры***: City[] cities (2 <= cities.length <= 1000).

Возвращаемый тип: *Result*.

***Пример:***

***Входные данные:***

```
cities = [ {
  "name" : "Brest",
  "x" : 52.1,
  "y" : 23.68333
}, {
  "name" : "Vitebsk",
  "x" : 55.18333,
  "y" : 30.16667
}, {
  "name" : "Gomel",
  "x" : 52.44167,
  "y" : 31.0
}, {
  "name" : "Grodno",
  "x" : 53.66667,
  "y" : 23.81667
}, {
  "name" : "Minsk",
  "x" : 53.91667,
  "y" : 27.55
}, {
  "name" : "Mogilev",
  "x" : 53.91667,
  "y" : 30.35
} ];
```

***Выходные данные***

```
result = {
  "first" : {
    "name" : "Vitebsk",
    "x" : 55.18333,
    "y" : 30.16667
  },
  "second" : {
    "name" : "Mogilev",
    "x" : 53.91667,
    "y" : 30.35
  }
};
```

А теперь,вот мой код,который я тестировал в Intellij Idea:

```
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String[] name1 = new String[]{"Brest", "Vitebsk", "Gomel" ,"Grodno" ,"Minsk" ,"Mogilev"};
        double [] x1 = new double[]{52.1, 55.18333 , 52.44167 ,53.66667 , 53.91667 , 53.91667};
        double [] y1 = new double[]{23.68333 , 30.16667 , 31.0 , 23.81667 , 27.55 , 30.35};
        System.out.println(findClosestCities(name1,x1,y1));
    }
    public static class City{
        String name;
         double x;
         double y;
        public City(String []name1, double [] x1 ,double [] y1){
            String[] name = new String[]{"Brest", "Vitebsk", "Gomel" ,"Grodno" ,"Minsk" ,"Mogilev"};
            double [] x = new double[]{52.1, 55.18333 , 52.44167 ,53.66667 , 53.91667 , 53.91667};
            double [] y = new double[]{23.68333 , 30.16667 , 31.0 , 23.81667 , 27.55 , 30.35};
        }
        public City (String name , double x , double y){
          this.name = name;
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
        }
        public City (){

        }
    }
    public static class Result{
        City first;
        City second;
        public Result(City city,City city1){
            first = (city);
            second = (city1);
        }
        public Result(){

        }
    }
    public static Result findClosestCities(String[] name, double[] x, double[] y) { //ввели массив объектов
        City city = new City(name, x, y);
        City city1 = new City(name, x, y);
        double min = 999999999.9;
        double min2 = 999999999.9;
        double distanceSquared = 0; // объявили переменную, в которую будем записывать значения в цикле(расстояние между двумя точками)
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {// цикл,кторый выводит значения расстояния и имя двух городов
            for (int j = 0; j < y.length - 1; j++) {
  distanceSquared = (((x[i] - x[j]) * (x[i] - x[j])) + ((y[i] - y[j]) * (y[i] - y[j])));//нашли расстояние между двумя точками
            if (min > distanceSquared && distanceSquared!=0) {
                min = distanceSquared;
                city.name = name[i];
                city.x = x[i];
                city.y = y[i];
                city1.name = name[j];
                city1.x = x[j];
                city1.y = y[j];
            }
            }
        }return new Result(city1, city);
    }
```

Как вы видите,я вводил не City [ ] cities ,а просто 3 массива.
Т.е автоматическая проверка не работает.И не могу переделать под ввод массива объектов.Не понимаю,как работать с вводными данными (в виде массива объектов).Помогите пожалуйста.
Возможно у меня ещё не правильный алгоритм(так же,охотно принимаю ответы по нему).Но , повторюсь, самое важное,это работа с массивами объектов.
В общем,буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; i < y.length - 1; i++) {` ???

Comment: `x[i] - x[i + 1]` ??? Почему вы сравниваете только соседние в списке города?

Comment: да,я у себя исправил второй цикл.

Comment: В общем,да,алгоритм нужно подправить.Но всё же.Основная проблема не в этом.Основная проблема,что я не понимаю,как работать с вводными данными из массива объектов.

Comment: Тогда измените (уменьшите) вопрос, чтобы он был о том, что действительно вызывает трудности.

Comment: Сформулировал и изменил.Спасибо.

Comment: Уберите вот этот конструктор: `public City(String []name1, double [] x1 ,double [] y1){ ... }`.

Comment: Конструктор убрал,вводные данные в функцию теперь City cities[ ].
Но я не знаю,какие теперь у меня имена переменных массива имен, координат x, координат y.
Как создать точно такой же массив,как подставляет платформа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
City[] cities = new City[] { 
  new City("Brest", 52.1, 23.68333),
  ...
};
System.out.println(findClosestCities(cities));

public static Result findClosestCities(City[] cities) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам!